# How to run the shell script periodically without using Crontab?

Tags: cron

I do not have previlage to use crontab -e to run my script.  Is there other way to periodically run my script?  Basically I need to run it once a week.

Answer (score 1):

If enabled and installed, you can use the `at` command.  However it is a one time only scheduling....you'd have to run a new `at` command within the thing that you wanted rescheduling.

Check out the `man` pages for help on the `at` command.

But remember, it is not always installed/enabled on all Linux/UNIX systems.

Comment: And somebody who doesn’t have the privilege to use `cron` might not be able to run `at`, either.

Comment: True, in general, cron and at are administered via two different access lists.

Answer (score 1):

The REAL answer to this is to contact your friendly neighborhood systems administrator, explain your problem, and ask them to enable cron access for you.  You should explain how your program runs, its resource requirements, and generally make a promise that you will not harm the system if you get cron access privs.

Comment: shouldn't you be posting both of these as one answer?

Comment: I figured they were two completely different answers.

Comment: Even if they were, its accepted practice to post them together. "You can do X, or alternatively Y" rather than posting two answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't/don't want to keep a terminal open, you could run it in [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)/[tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) or with [`nohup`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup).

Examples:

```
screen sh -c 'while sleep 7d; do mycommand; done'
```

or

```
tmux 'while sleep 7d; do mycommand; done'
```

Note: these commands will run `mycommand` the first time *after* a week and then periodically, not directly. Change according to preference.

See the projects' documentation for more info on attaching/detaching sessions.

(`7d` is GNU specific, I believe. Just put `604800` there instead if the `sleep` version only supports seconds.)

Comment: As a systems administrator, I really hate seeing these type of things.  They take up job slots, and are not very reliable, if the machine gets booted, then the job of course stops and thus you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to have a cronjob running on a different machine, that uses `ssh` to execute a certain command on the target server. If you set up key based login, this will be easy.

Just set up a cronjob on another machine that looks like e.g.

```
0 0 * * 7   /usr/bin/ssh remoteuser@remotehost mycommand
```

With the exception of the remote server being offline at the execution time, this would be reliable over remote server restarts and other things.

Comment: I'm sure an admin would be happy about this one.